# ¿Por qué TableRowSorter omite los ceros de mi tabla?

Tags: java

Buen día, me he encontrado con un inconveniente a la hora de ordenar los datos de mi tabla, parece que TableRowSorter omite los '0', no tengo idea de porqué pase eso, no sé si alguien conozca la solución para ello.

Aquí muestro una imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que '20mm' debería estar hasta el final, pero no sé porqué lo coloca antes que el número 2. El código implementado para la tabla es el siguiente:

```
void ver(){
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        archivo = new File("datos.txt");
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        //Aquí creo el modelo de la tabla
        DefaultTableModel model_tabla = new DefaultTableModel();
        model_tabla.addColumn("Fecha");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Velocidad de corte");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Profundidad del corte");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Tipo de disco");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Material");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Energía");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Tipo de suelo");
        model_tabla.addColumn("Número de cuchilla");
        model_tabla.addColumn("IP Cuchilla");
        //model_tabla.addColumn("Tipo de fallo");
        //model_tabla.addColumn("Vida útil aproximada");
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
            if(linea!=""){
                String []rowfields = (linea.split("  "));
                model_tabla.addRow(rowfields);
            }       
        }
        br.close();
        //Establezco el modelo a mi tabla
        tabla.setModel(model_tabla);
        //Aquí el tablerowsorter
        TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(model_tabla);
        //Y aquí le asgigno el ordenamiento a mi tabla
        tabla.setRowSorter(sorter);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tú podrías arreglar el orden de los datos pasando por manipulaciones *oscuras*, pero creo que el problema principal es que no estás introduciendo tus datos como enteros. Yo declararía esos datos como enteros y luego los presentaría añadiéndole aparte la unidad de medida. De ese modo creo que podrás ordenar correctamente.

Comment: Tengo otra columna sólo con números, aunque también los agrego a la tabla como strings, y de igual manera no los ordena, parece que sólo toma como referencia el primer dígito. ¿Hay alguna opción para que tome la cadena completa?

Comment: Tienes que agregarlos como enteros en vez de como strings, precisamente por eso te los ordena mal, porque los ordena como strings.

Comment: El problema es que leo los datos de un archivo de texto antes de agregarlos, entonces siento que tendría que hacer un proceso 'innecesario' al convertir a enteros, porque de igual manera debería ordenar los datos correctamente. ¿Existe alguna otra manera de ordenar un jtable?

Comment: No es un proceso innecesario. Más bien aunque lo recibas de un archivo y son datos numéricos que vienen como string, deberías guardarlos como lo que son. Imagina que más adelante necesites hacer cálculos con esos datos o almacenarlos en una base de datos. Si no los conviertes al tipo de datos respectivos estarás arrastrando siempre el mismo problema. Con los datos hay que ser objetivos y guardarlos como lo que son, no como otra cosa. De lo contrario, tendrás problemas con cada operación de cálculo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Parece que aún con la conversión a enteros sigue ordenándolos mal, o no sé si esta línea "tabla.setValueAt(datos[a], a, 5);" establezca los datos de esa columna como enteros. datos[] es un arreglo de enteros, pero sigue igual.